# React: using a function incorrectly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a function calling another in code from work, but I'm getting errors about invalid use of hooks.

```
const Vis = ({ queryString }) => {
  const [userQueryString, setUserQueryString] = useState(queryString);
  queryString = `some query`;
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(FOO_QUERY, {
    variables: { queryString },
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      return;
    },
  });

  // this is the function that fails
  const handleSubmit = (params) => {
    useQuery(params.userQueryString);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <RenderGraph data={formatData(data)}>
        <QueryForm
          userQueryString={queryString}
          queryFunction={handleSubmit}>
        </QueryForm>
      </RenderGraph>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I try to use the `useQuery` function, I get an error about hooks.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Maybe I'm using `useQuery` incorrectly?

Comment: I tried that, I get a bad request when I reload the page.

Comment: Yes, `useQuery(params.userQueryString);` can't be called inside an event handler like that. It needs to be called at the top-level of your function (ie: within `Vis` so that it runs every time `Vis` is rendered). What are you trying to do by calling it within the event handler function?

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking. Are you aware that `useQuery` is a hook (you can tell because its name starts with the word `use`), and is therefore subject to the rules of hook usage?

Comment: Yes, what @NickParsons said. I totally missed that. I deleted my previous comment

Comment: @NickParsons thank you for the response! I basically want to do what that function is doing but from inside my event handler.

Comment: @easythrees Is that `useQuery()` hook from Apollo? (also, what's the value of params.userQueryString?)

Comment: @easythrees: Don't think of hooks as "functions", think of them as "hooks". They participate in the React component lifecycle, and can't be called like normal functions.

Comment: Ah okay. I was looking at the Apollo/GraphQL docs and they mention being able to use `useLazyQuery(...)` manually, maybe I should try that...

Comment: When the component mounts, use Query will run so if you console.log(loading) it will show true in the first couple of seconds, now what you can do is, where you have written const {loading ....} = useQuery, you also have a function called refetch,  so you can use that to refetch data but you will have to make sure that your QueryKey changes or else it will use cached data. So you can remove useQuery inside the function and use refetch()

Comment: I'm assuming by QueryKey, you mean the query string?